# Customizing Textselection dialog of webview

Tags: android

I want to customize Textselection dialog of webview.(When we press longclick at that time appear)
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can customize that.  Android 2.2 and below don't even support the long click response function ( i.e. nothing happens when you long press).

Long click is supported for WebView on Android 2.3+ and brings up the "copy and paste" dialog, but webview implements it by temporarily setting itself into WebTextView mode which allows user to select words to clipborad.  The dialog you see when the long press is brought up at that time. [WebView.performLongClick()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/webkit/WebView.java#WebView.performLongClick%28%29)

Since WebTextView is a private class, there is no way you can access it. So, I think even if you can override the onPerformLongClick() method and prevent the dialog from showing up, you can't get the dialog and customize it.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use onPerformLongClick() for android OS 4.1+ ? I have to override default text selection option dialog on customized webview.