# Android. How to get String from html by longclicking on it

Tags: android, webview

Help somebody, I am stuck.
The goal is to view html text with pictures and etc. and to be able catch longClick events on pieces of plain text. And then get this txt and do something with it.

Comment: have you even tried something?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a custom application to load html documents then you should have the look at [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) documentation for it. It contains everything to guide you.

Comment: I find these topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058694/onlongclick-for-plain-text-inside-of-a-webview
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821479/customizing-textselection-dialog-of-webview
and that's why I ask.